# Writing a spec for partial used in the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec3

I'm trying to test a partial included in a layout. Following is my setup.

I have a base controller which is based for several other controllers.

```
BaseController < ApplciationController
  layout 'base' 
end
```

So, in the `base` layout I have included a partial `_my_partial`. I'm not sure how exactly to test , if the layout renders the partial.

Ex: I can test it from a controller action spec which inherit by base controller.

```
UsersController < BaseController
  def index

  end
end 

#users controller spec #index action
get :index
response.should render_template(:partial => "_my_partial")
```

But this seems to me little odd, because I actually want to test if the partial in included in every controller which inherits it. I'm thinking this test doesn't implies that.

Any ideas on how write this spec which make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - it's not really the right place. Controller specs are for testing controllers (ie that stuff inside your controller class), not really for testing which aspects of which views.

To test what shows up in views, you can either use view specs, or write features - either one is more standard for testing what shows up on the page.

Comment: Hey @taryn thanks for the reply. your answer make sense, quick follow up question ,  Since the layout is across all the views, is it acceptable to test only one view (which has the layout) and assume everything else  should also be ok ? or is there any specific was of testing the layout, without binding to any particular view. :)

Comment: Sounds good to me. No need to duplicate your specs too much unless there's a reasonable chance that your spec has different results for this particular case.

Comment: But feature specs are slow and preferred only for end-end features testing. So `spec/views` is the right place(since he is not testing end-end feature)?

Comment: This is true - but different people draw the line differently depending on their testing preferences.